# In Blender 2.82a what is the shortcut to get out of loop cut state?

Tags: interface

[image]

I am stuck with the loop cut tool enforcing me to click and by not vanishing when I use Esc key.
Could someone tell me what the shortcut is come out of this state.

Comment: Have you selected to the loopcut tool in the left toolbar?

Comment: Yes I figured I just needed to click on `select box` mode in the left toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get out of loop cut mode, one can simply click on the `select box` in the left toolbar.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get out of loop cut mode, Simply Click "ENTER" Key. You will get out of it!

Comment: Your suggestion won't work when the tool in the toolbar is selected, which was the case for the poster. For cancelling the regular loop cut operator it is better to use ESC as the other existing answer suggests, as this prevents any unintended loop cut from happening.

Answer (score 0):

To cancel any tool press the  <kbd>Esc</kbd>  key.